# should job schedulers be shared in a soa environment?

Tags: soa

Say for example, an accounting service has a need to schedule ledger update jobs,

1. should the accounting service include it's own scheduler? or,
2. should job scheduling be a shared service?

I guess option (a) makes the service more autonomous?

What other criteria should be involved in making the decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Job scheduler is usually an off-the-shelf component (like [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)) so you'd probably use that (many times it is embedded in the service host anyway).

In any event when you decide whether or not to create a separate service vs. having a component/library used internally within services you should consider the overhead of maintaining it, developing it as a separate unit etc. (see the [nano-services](http://arnon.me/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Nanoservices.pdf) antipattern)