# reporting functionality in SOA services

Tags: soa

I'm looking to design a SOA service which in addition to its main requirements has a requirement for a small number of reports.

When should SOA services (a) include their own reporting functionality, and when should (b) reports be made available as part of a separate reporting service?

I guess (a) makes the service more self-contained, but (b) should probably be preferred when the organisation already has reporting services deployed?

Comment: I think the answer is going to be pretty similar to a previous question that I posted a while back: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351031/should-job-schedulers-be-shared-in-a-soa-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can/should report on individual services if the report is self contained and relates to data that changes frequently.

It is ok to use a centralised reporting when the data is immutable i.e. historic copy of the data. This way the services are still the owners of the data (and responsible for updating the data) and the data is still available for cross-service reports. This is a pattern I call aggregated reporting (you can see a draft of it [here](http://www.manning.com/free/excerpt_rotem_a.html))

You can see an article I published on infoQ called [bridging the gap between BI & SOA](http://www.infoq.com/articles/BI-and-SOA)